# starting new need help

Tags: live

The hope is to be doing interviews in breweries and restraunts the guy who was set to do it has bailed and so has his equipment amd knowledge. I was wondering whats the best starter equipment to get great audio and the software. Any list or links for help or equipmemt would be GREATLY apprecaited! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

For gear, I like this list: http://www.desktop-documentaries.com/cinematic-documentary-gear-package.html

For software (I assume for editing), Premiere Pro is very capable and easygoing on beginners.  Download a trial and see how you like it!

Bear in mind, that both take time to learn in order to produce quality results, so unless you're a quick study, or your project is very simple, factor the learning curve into the cost of doing it yourself.

Comment: I have Lumix G6 like in the article you provide. With same lens. That lens is 46mm in diameter, but article advice to buy with it Tiffen 52mm Variable ND Filter... Will it fit there? I am looking right now for filter, and that difference in sizes disturb me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular filter, but for indoor shots I doubt you'll really need an ND filter.  Try some test shots in your target venues (or similar lit environments) without a filter and see if the footage works.

Comment: I am talking here about 46mm vs 52mm... It sounds like filter from the post will not match with camera from post...